# Where is the appropriate place to put application configuration files for each popular operating system?

Tags: design, cross-platform, configuration

Before writing this question, I'd like to state that I use Linux on a daily basis, which is why I'm creating this post to extend my knowledge of the other main operating systems I'm concerned about, Mac OS and Windows.

I'm developing a NodeJS application that needs to read a configuration in order to understand what to do, and allow the user to customize some of the inner workings of the application through this configuration.

However, this application is also cross-platform.  And I know that operating systems have different file structures for their own convenience.
On a lot of Linux operating systems (if not all) I know that configurations are most commonly put in `~/.config/<app>` or likely `~/.<app>/config` if the first is not applicable...

Although, my knowledge does not expand far enough to know if that's the same for Windows and Mac OS?

What is considered the best place to put application configurations on Linux, Mac OS, and Windows?

Comment: For linux you might be interested in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and [XDG specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Comment: @CodesInChaos, Ah yes.  I've heard briefly of XDG.  Definitely something I should look into.

Comment: Note that many applications that use XDG, only support `XDG_*_HOME` and not those preference ordered search paths.

Comment: Your question mentions OS configuration and application configuration as if they were one and the same. I'd take a stab that you actually mean application configuration - correct?

Comment: Yes.  I'm making application that has a configuration.  But it's also cross-platform.  So my question was where the appropriate place to put a application's configuration on Mac OS, Linux, and Windows (since they all have different locations for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses the [`%APPDATA%`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-appdata-folder) directory for user specific application configuration files. The [`%PROGRAMDATA%`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716245.aspx) folder is used for system wide application configuration files, though it appears that Windows Store apps may not be able to use `%PROGRAMDATA%`.

The [registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) is a hierarchical database included as part of Windows that can also store some config data as key-value pairs.

---

For Mac OS X, the `~/Library` folder is [usually used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/410013/3342206), with `/Library` for global configs.

Usually these are nested further, so your preferences would go in `~/Library/Preferences/` and some other files would go in `~/Library/Application Support`

---

Note that in all of the above cases, you'll probably want to put your configurations under your app's name within the base location.

Comment: And also the registry, .config files, XML files, INI files, databases, bespoke web services etc etc etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "the registry"? I'm a bit confused.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @RobbieDee Added the registry as you were commenting. .config files, XML files, INI files, and databases are all storage formats, not locations. Web services I'll leave to someone else to talk about.

Comment: @Jamen [The registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) is a central configuration storage on windows which you could use instead of configuration files. I recommend using it only where necessary.

Comment: My point was the "appropriate place" has differed vastly over the many versions of windows there has been.

Comment: @RobbieDee True, Microsoft does seem to be very indecisive in these regards.